# How to Count [Combined] line length of multiple files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a counter to see how many lines of code I'm making for this project I'm working on in total. So what I'm trying to do is make a simple JavaScript file that counts every line in multiple files and adds it up into a total. I need any empty lines to be counted, but then have it be outputted to a separate box in the HTML content.

Here's what the HTML page, or something similar, would be like.

## HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #div1  {
      display: block;
      background: #444444;
      width: 100%
      height: 100%;
    }
    #div1 .container  {
      align: center;
      overflow: auto;
      width: 75%;
      height: 75%;
      display: block;
      background: #666666;
    }
    #div2  {
      display: block;
      background: #444444;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    #div2 .container  {
      overflow: auto;
      width: 75%;
      height: 75%;
      display: block;
      background: #666666;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
    <h2>I Failed <u>391</u> Times!*</h2>
    <h6><i>*Before Giving Up</i></h6>
    </div>
    <div id="div1" class="div">
      <div class="container">
        <p>INSERT TOTAL LINES FROM 3 DIFFERENT FILES COMBINED</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" class="div">
      <div class="container">
        <p>INSERT TOTAL USED LINES FROM 3 DIFFERENT FILES COMBINED</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## JavaScript

```
/*function myWorkingUnNeededFunction()  {;
var attempts = "381 + Counting";
var hdr1 = document.createElement("H2");
var txt1 = document.createTextNode("");
var i;
hdr1.appendChild("txt1");
document.getElementById("header").appendChild("hdr1");
for(i = 0; i < attempts.length; i++)  
{
  document.getElementByTagName("h2").innerHTML = "'Failed' + i + 'Times'";
}
myWorkingUnNeededFunction();
}
*/
function myBrokenCounter1()  {
  /* REALLY, REALLY long code of just failure... trust me, you do NOT want to see... I'll just show what I think could work, but not actually fill in certain parts as I am unaware. */
  var lines;
  var counter;
  var lines = document.getElementByClassName("div");
  if(lines.id = "div1")  {
   document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = counterWithEmptyLines();
   document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = counterWithUsedLines();
  }
  }
  /* What I was going for is that there will be two counters; one counting the line length of ALL lines, and one counting the line length of ALL **USED** lines. If the div class has a id of div1, the total counter will go to div1 with empty lines. Otherwise, it will go to div2 with the used & empty lines as well. */
  function counterWithLUsedLines()  {
    /* more fails with no knowledge of how to do it */
  }
  function counterWithLEmptyLines()  {
    /* EVEN more fails with no knowledge of how to do it */
  }
```

I've tried. The HTML doesn't lie; I've literally tried about 390 times before giving up. There should be two seperate files; one script.js file which writes it to the HTML file, and ofc, the counter.html file with the script linked.

Comment: Can you show us your failed attempts with counterWithLEmptyLines() and counterWithLUsedLines()? How did you try to access your files with JS? From a browser?

Comment: Did you try something like the described here: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html

Comment: In general, accessing local file system (if it's the case) via JS/Browser is not a much of a good idea (from a security point of view). As far as I know, modern browsers don't like such ideas. Long ago I succeeded to read, create and write text files from Internet Explorer 6 using its access to ActiveX Windows API in my JS code. I don't think (but didn't really checked) that modern IE browsers support this.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
1. document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML.split("\n").length;
2. document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML.split("\n").filter(function(l){return l.length;}).length;
```

`text.split("\n").length` gives us lines count
`.filter(function(l){return l.length;})` filters out empty lines